# Magento2: I need to create custom dropdowns attribute changes the values on the basis of another dropdown attribute in catalog product admin

Tags: magento2

```
I have two dropdown attributes in admin
 1. Product dropdown attribute - m1(val1, val2, val3) m2 (val1, val2)
 2. Material dropdown attribute  - m1, m2 

if m1 - val1, val2, val3
if m2 - val1, val2
```

I need to change the values of product dropdown attribute on the selection of Material dropdown values m1 and m2

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: on which page you want this dropdowns ?

Comment: in add products attributes?

Comment: Use jquery for your select dropdown